# Print ReportViewer Report to PDF on Azure WebApp. Get General GDI Error

Tags: azure, reportviewer, gdi, azure-web-app-service

I have code that will take a ReportViewer report and print it through PrintDialog. However, when I move it to Azure WebApp, I get a General GDI Error. I've been looking for a solution, but all I find is that Azure is blocking most GDI calls. It's crapping out on the Export method below. Any advised work around?

```
    private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            m_streams.Add(stream);
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CreateStream: " + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    public void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        try
        {
            string deviceInfo =
              @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
            Warning[] warnings;
            m_streams = new List<Stream>();
            report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Export: " + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this a Basic, Standard or Free App Service Plan?  I believe this may be problematic due to ActiveX - you might need to think about moving this to a Web Role in a cloud service, or a straigh up VM

Comment: It's Standard. I've seen the workarounds you mentioned. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe the problem is that Azure's GDI doesn't support EMF, which is used by Telerik Reporting's desktop viewers and ReportProcessor when printing. However, in [R2 2018 SP1](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/reporting/release-history/progress-telerik-reporting-r2-2018-sp1-12-1-18-620) the issue is addressed and the printing format can be adjusted so the engine would print using Bitmap instead of Metafile, which is supported by Azure. The rendering extension in question is called [ImagePrint](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/configuring-rendering-extensions) and can be set up through the application's configuration file like this:

```html
<configuration> 
  <!-- The configSectins element should be the first child element of configuration --> 
  <configSections>
  <section
    name="Telerik.Reporting"
    type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be"
    allowLocation="true"
    allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>
       
  <Telerik.Reporting> 
    <extensions> 
      <render> 
        <extension name="IMAGEPrint"> 
          <parameters> 
            <parameter name="OutputFormat" value="PNG"/> 
            <parameter name="DpiX" value="300"/> 
            <parameter name="DpiY" value="300"/> 
          </parameters> 
        </extension> 
      </render> 
    </extensions> 
  </Telerik.Reporting> 
</configuration>
```

The **DpiX** and **DpiY** parameters are not mandatory, but since they are set to 96 by default, this might lead to pixelated image, especially when printing to a printer with higher DPI, so it's better to configure them through the app.config as well.

Answer (score -1):

All Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked. For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps do not require access to Windows UI functionality. However, one common pattern that is affected is PDF file generation

As mentioned in this document https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox - The following PDF generators are supported:

•   SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher 
(note that this currently does not work in Functions apps in Consumptions mode)

•   EVOPDF: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution

•   Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan Basic or higher